# Domain of the following function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is the domain of the following function? 
$$h(x,y,z)=x^zy^{1-z}$$

To me it is $R^3$, but my professor claims that it is:
$D=\{(x, y, z) ∈ \Bbb R^3: x>0, y>0 \}$

Are not $x^z$ and $y^z$ defined for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: Hint: Think about what happens when $x = z = 0$.

Comment: "Are not $x^z$ and $y^z$ defined for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$?". I mean, it is rather easy a statement to back up (or otherwise): look at $(-\sqrt 3)^{\sqrt2}$, think about your precalculus and you can tell us what that is.

Comment: No, they're not defined for all $x,y$, unless the exponent is an integer. Actually the definition of $x^z$, for instance, is $x^z\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{z\ln x}$, so that $\ln x$ has to be defined.

Comment: Thank you, bu then why is $0^x$ well defined when $x>0$. If I use the def you mentioned I would obtain $e^{xln0} $ which is clearly not well defined in R.

Comment: Also, if I write $x^2=e^{2lnx}$ the I should set $x>0$, but we know that $x^2 $ is well defined for every x. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When we want to define some exponential function $$x\mapsto a^x$$ for arbitrary base $a,$ we need the base to be positive if we want the function to be defined, real-valued and continuous on some *interval* of the real line.